# How can I replace my site's dlls without loosing session data (prevent application restart)?

Tags: asp.net

When I modify my code I have to upload the project's DLL I modified it, but the problem is that I loos data I put in session because my application restarts.
Is this normal? or I should do something to prevent the restart?.
I feel that this is wrong because imagine if you're working on shopping site and people buying goods and suddenly they lost every thing they put in the shopping cart (because you save their choices in session.
Is there a way to do this in Asp.net?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From you question it looks like you are using sessions in proc (that is, in the IIS process).

This means that whenever IIS restarts you would indeed lose session data (as would be the case if you update the DLLs in the bin folder).

To solve this, there are several options:

- move session information to SQL Server
- move session information to a dedicated session server
- remove all dependencies on sessions from your application.

See the MSDN documentation of the [`sessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) configuration element.